# MathJax in achievements does not render correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, achievements-dialog, mathjax

The MathJax is not rendering correctly in the **Recent achievements** dialog for this [post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/37027/21025).
Instead of the plain text it is displaying the MathJax code.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: MathJax in achievements]

---

**Update:**

Based on one of the comment, I verified the achievements dialog from the MathJax enabled SE site Puzzling. Viewing from there also I can see the render issue.

Screenshot taken from Puzzling SE:

[image: MathJax from Puzzling SE]

Comment: Which SE site were you on when you took this screenshot? Most sites do not include the MathJax library.

Comment: @mmyers: Just i checked, when i'm in puzzling SE and open the achievements dialog, still the same issue.

Comment: Is it really *an issue* though? Do you remember it rendering before in "achievements"?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268968/dollar-signs-in-notifications-render-with-mathjax-on-some-sites -- rendering is solely dependent on whether the current site has it enabled, not the site the notification came from.

Answer (score 2):

Most sites do not have mathjax support, because they don't need it and it adds a hefty amount of traffic (an has an impact on page rendering etc, etc, etc...).

The result is that when you open your inbox on sites that do not have mathjax, posts that have mathjax in the title will not render it as such.

Comment: Hope Puzzling.SE have MathJax enabled, I open the achievements dialog from the puzzling also causing the [same issue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oqQV2.png)

Comment: Hm. The dialog doesn't trigger a re-rendering by mathjax, probably because it isn't present on the page on initial load. Not sure it should either.

Comment: I closed the browser. Newly opened a browser then directly landing in to puzzling.SE by typing the URL and open the achievements dialog, still the same.

Comment: Yes. That's the point of my last comment. The dialog is loaded via an AJAX call - which doesn't trigger a mathjax re-render.